# Mesh On always top Of the View or Sean

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I am working on one 3d diagram and like bar or line ..
I am using three.js v60 Because already most code done with that version  so .. Now I need to put legends  I have 3D-Object  for legends but it rotate and scale with camera .. I don't want that .. I want that always stay on top left corner as it is .. so when I get data URL of canvas i get in image ...

any suggestion I can show you the current deployed prototype  here

http://ameetrana.yzi.me/demos/3dLineModel/

currently I have set fix html element but it will not come in image when i get image from canvas

we can inspect code in linechart.js model

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

R60 examples for possible solutions:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprites.html

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html